# How to format log data before forwarding them as JSON to elasticsearch?

Tags: syslog, logstash, elasticsearch, syslog-ng

I log all events on a system to a JSON file via `syslog-ng`:

```
destination d_json { file("/var/log/all_syslog_in_json.log" perm(0666) template("{\"@timestamp\": \"$ISODATE\", \"facility\": \"$FACILITY\", \"priority\": \"$PRIORITY\", \"level\": \"$LEVEL\", \"tag\": \"$TAG\", \"host\": \"$HOST\", \"program\": \"$PROGRAM\", \"message\": \"$MSG\"}\n")); };

log { source(s_src); destination(d_json); };
```

This file is monitored by `logstash` (2.0 beta)  which forwards the content to `elasticsearch` (2.0 RC1):

```
input
{
  file
  {
    path => "/var/log/all_syslog_in_json.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => json
    sincedb_path => "/etc/logstash/db_for_watched_files.db"
    type => "syslog"
  }

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elk.example.com"]
        index => "logs"
    }
}
```

I then visualize the results in `kibana`.

This setup works fine, except that `kibana` does not expand the `message` part:

[image]

Is it possible to tweak any of the elements of the processing chain to enable to expansion of `messages` (so that its components are at the same level as `path` or `type`?

EDIT: as requested, a few lines from `/var/log/all_syslog_in_json.log`

```
{"@timestamp": "2015-10-21T20:14:05+02:00", "facility": "auth", "priority": "info", "level": "info", "tag": "26", "host": "eu2", "program": "sshd", "message": "Disconnected from 10.8.100.112"}
{"@timestamp": "2015-10-21T20:14:05+02:00", "facility": "authpriv", "priority": "info", "level": "info", "tag": "56", "host": "eu2", "program": "sshd", "message": "pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user nagios"}
{"@timestamp": "2015-10-21T20:14:05+02:00", "facility": "authpriv", "priority": "info", "level": "info", "tag": "56", "host": "eu2", "program": "systemd", "message": "pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user nagios"}
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines from `/var/log/all_syslog_in_json.log`? Have you tried running the `message` field through the `json` filter to expand it?

Comment: @GregL: I edited my question with your request. I am new to logstash, so how exacltly can I "*run the `message` field through the `json` filter to expand it*"?

Comment: You'd need to read the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) on the `json` filter, create a `filter` stanza in the config and add an appropriate `json` stanza inside it.

Comment: @GregL: I see, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you. It seems that it is not possible to dynamically map the fields but I will be required to specifically add one `add_field`entry per field in my JSON, right?

Comment: No, it'll do it all for you. a config like this `filter { json { source => "message" } }`, will result in fields called `facility`, `priority`, etc..

Comment: Have you tried using the `json_lines` codec instead of `json`?  I've got log sources that look just like the example lines you gave, and `json_lines` works Just Fine to parse them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using the wrong codec on your input, you need to use json_lines, from [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html):

```
If you are streaming JSON messages delimited by \n then see the json_lines codec.
```

Use [this codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json_lines.html) instead. Alternatively, you could ignore the codec on the input and send these through a json filter, which is how I always do it.

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
```